# Pycharm won't let me test my code

Tags: python, testing, pycharm, limits

The green play button to test the code is grayed out.  This is after, I created a new project after deleting an old one.  Initially, it kept trying to search for a file that was long deleted after the old project, and I'd put the code in the new project.  It therefore kept giving an error.

Later on, the green play and debug buttons were completely grayed out and unclickable.

Here's the code.  It's just bare bones for now; part of an online course I'm doing for simple top-down game design, since I'm still a noob.

```
def Initialize():
    # Initialize game
    print("Initializing")


def ContinueGame():
    # Return false if game should end, true if game is not over
    print("Checking to see if we should continue")
    return True


def DoRound():
    # Perform one round of the game
    print("Doing one round")


# Initialize game
Initialize()

# while game not over
while ContinueGame():
    # Do a round of the game
    DoRound()
```

As you can see, it gives no instructions to call from the old file.

I'm using pycharm community edition 2016.3